# Detect application termination with react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Is there a way to detect when a react-native application will terminate?

I was thinking of `componentWillUnmount` at the main component level, do you think that's best way to do it?

I would like to send a "Save" request to the server before. I'm not sure if that's appropriate while the application in terminating, any better suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: hi @alexmngn did you manage to do it?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9348, it is not possible to do any cleanup on the JS side, you need to do it natively with *applicationWillTerminate* (which also means sync stuff between js and native code). I have an issue with my app terminating while running in the background, and I'm really looking forward to finding an explanation on how to do that.

Comment: hi do you found any good solution?

Comment: sorry I don't remember, that is too old. What does chatGPT suggest?

Comment: I dont have chatGPT account bro

Comment: https://ctxt.io/2/AADQQg2zFA
Here is the copy paste from chatGPT4. I don't think I can add it here StackOverflow should refuse the response. 
Let me know if it is useful ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably send an event when native method `applicationWillTerminate` is invoked and then send the request from JS code after receiving such event.

Comment: I tried and it looks like the event has not the time to be handle by the js before the termination...